# Understanding Java Iterator Example

Tags: java

I am working through HackerRank for Java and found the following problem regarding Iterator https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-iterator/problem.

Can someone explain a few items:

How is the initial scanner working (i.e. the one right after the main function)? If you see the problem statement it says there will be an unknown number of integers at the start (unknown number of integers, followed by "###" character, then we want to print the remaining unknown number of strings), and we create two variables m and n to work with the scanner function. But I'm not understanding the for loop and how we are setting the parameter `(i=0;i<n;i++);` Can someone explain how the `i < n` part works? Isn't `n` an arbitrary and unknown number?

Similarly, how is the Iterator function at the bottom working? Isn't it just printing out all of the elements in the ArrayList? Or if there is a break in the Iterator, the elements that are printed out are only the ones after it?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{


       static Iterator func(ArrayList mylist){
          Iterator it=mylist.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext()){
             Object element = it.next();
             if (element.equals("###"))

                break;
            }
          return it;

       }

       @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
       public static void main(String []args){
          ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          int n = sc.nextInt();
          int m = sc.nextInt();
          for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
             mylist.add(sc.nextInt());
          }


          mylist.add("###");
          for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
             mylist.add(sc.next());
          }

          Iterator it=func(mylist);
          while(it.hasNext()){
             Object element = it.next();
             System.out.println((String)element);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help with the editing, I was just in the process of doing that

Comment: Warning: you are using raw types (`ArrayList` and `Iterator`). Do not use raw types, rather provide the necessary type argument, e.g. `ArrayList` should be `ArrayList<Object>` in your case.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Everything was the default code provided by HackerRank. The only thing I added was two lines of code:   Object element = it.next();
             if (element.equals("###"))